# How to build an embedding layer in Tensorflow RNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, word-embedding

I'm building an RNN LSTM network to classify texts based on the writers' age (binary classification - young / adult).

Seems like the network does not learn and suddenly starts overfitting:

[image: rnn_overfitting]
**Red: train

Blue: validation**

One possibility could be that the data representation is not good enough. I just sorted the unique words by their frequency and gave them indices. E.g.:

```
unknown -> 0
the     -> 1
a       -> 2
.       -> 3
to      -> 4
```

So I'm trying to replace that with word embedding.
I saw a couple of examples but I'm not able to implement it in my code. Most of the examples look like this:

```
embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, hidden_size], -1, 1))
inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, input_data)
```

Does this mean we're building a layer that **learns** the embedding? I thought that one should download some Word2Vec or Glove and just use that.

Anyway let's say I want to build this embedding layer...
If I use these 2 lines in my code I get an error:

> TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'indices' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

So I guess I have to change the `input_data` type to `int32`. So I do that (it's all indices after all), and I get this:

> TypeError: inputs must be a sequence

I tried wrapping `inputs` (argument to `tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn`) with a list: `[inputs]` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45217776/900394), but that produced another error:

> ValueError: Input size (dimension 0 of inputs) must be accessible via
>   shape inference, but saw value None.

---

**Update:**

I was unstacking the tensor `x` before passing it to `embedding_lookup`. I moved the unstacking after the embedding.

Updated code:

```
MIN_TOKENS = 10
MAX_TOKENS = 30
x = tf.placeholder("int32", [None, MAX_TOKENS, 1])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, N_CLASSES]) # 0.0 / 1.0
...
seqlen = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None]) #list of each sequence length*
embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([VOCAB_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE], -1, 1))
inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, x) #x is the text after converting to indices
inputs = tf.unstack(inputs, MAX_POST_LENGTH, 1)
outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=seqlen) #---> Produces error
```

**seqlen: I zero-padded the sequences so all of them have the same list size, but since the actual size differ, I prepared a list describing the length without the padding.*

New error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer basic_lstm_cell_1 is incompatible with
>   the layer: expected ndim=2, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None,
>   1, 64]

*64 is the size of each hidden layer.*

It's obvious that I have a problem with the dimensions... How can I make the inputs fit the network after embedding?

Answer (score 4):

From the [tf.nn.static_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn) , we can see the `inputs` arguments to be:

> A length T list of inputs, each a Tensor of shape [batch_size, input_size]

So your code should be something like:

```
x = tf.placeholder("int32", [None, MAX_TOKENS])
...
inputs = tf.unstack(inputs, axis=1)
```

Comment: That solved my `ValueError` problem (+ adjusting the input accordingly - reshaping the batches from **(BATCH_SIZE, MAX_TOKENS, 1)** to **(BATCH_SIZE, MAX_TOKENS)** to match with the new `x` shape). This however didn't solve the learning problem. The graphs now look like: [this](https://i.imgur.com/HfARpBi.png). I guess you deserve the bounty though (and +1).

Comment: Can you share the entire code, so that I can try it out locally?

Comment: Instead of assigning unique values to the words, its better to assign a pretained embedding vectors from `glove` or `word2vec` and not train them.

Comment: I tried also doing that (glove). The graphs looked similar of what I posted originally. So surely I'm doing something wrong. Here's the code (using glove): [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kQEhm30vKRsVR35ZBa3ngQlGnlmwWGQD)

Comment: From the code, i see that you change the embedding vector of glove to a single value using `np.linalg.norm`, a single value may not be good enough to represent the word. I recommend you to change this.

Answer (score 1):

[tf.squeeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) is a method that removes dimensions of size 1 from the tensor. If the end goal is to have the input shape as [None,64], then put a line similar to `inputs = tf.squeeze(inputs)` and that would fix your problem.

Comment: It didn't work. Where do I put that? If I put it just before the call to `static_rnn`, I get another error: `Inputs must be a sequence`

Comment: Try wrapping inputs in brackets to make `tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, [inputs], dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=seqlen)`

Comment: I wrote that I tried that. Read the full post please

Comment: Did you do it with the `tf.sqeeze`? Could you also print the dtype and shape of the inputs right before the rnn call?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my first comment, I tried your suggestion with `squeeze` and it didn't work. The types are `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor` for `x`, `sqlen`, and `keep_prob`, and `dict` for `weights` and `biases`