# Implementation of Embedded Layer for CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi there I have been trying to follow the 2 examples:

1) [How to do text classification with CNNs, TensorFlow and word embedding](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-do-text-classification-using-tensorflow-word-embeddings-and-cnn-edae13b3e575)

2) [How to build an embedding layer in Tensorflow RNN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168247/how-to-build-an-embedding-layer-in-tensorflow-rnn)

However, I have been running into following error for the example 1,

```
Input 0 of layer conv2d_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 100, 20]
```

and the following error for example 2.

```
ValueError: Layer conv2d_1 expects 1 inputs, but it received 100 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'unstack:0' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:1' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:2' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:3' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:4' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:5' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:6' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:7' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:8' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:9' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:10' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:11' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:12' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:13' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:14' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:15' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:16' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:17' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:18' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:19' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:20' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:21' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:22' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:23' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:24' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:25' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:26' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:27' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:28' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:29' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:30' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:31' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:32' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:33' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:34' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:35' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:36' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:37' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:38' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:39' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:40' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:41' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:42' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:43' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:44' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:45' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:46' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:47' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:48' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:49' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:50' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:51' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:52' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:53' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:54' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:55' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:56' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:57' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:58' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:59' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:60' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:61' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:62' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:63' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:64' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:65' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:66' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:67' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:68' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:69' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:70' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:71' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:72' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:73' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:74' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:75' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:76' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:77' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:78' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:79' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:80' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:81' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:82' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:83' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:84' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:85' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:86' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:87' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:88' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:89' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:90' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:91' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:92' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:93' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:94' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:95' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:96' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:97' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:98' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack:99' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>]
```

I have change the code instead of using `word_list = tf.unstack(word_vectors, axis=1)` I have changed to the following implementation to get around the errors but I do not know if the implementation is correct.

```
word_vectors = tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence(
    x, vocab_size=n_words, embed_dim=EMBEDDING_SIZE)

word_list = tf.reshape( word_vectors, [-1, MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH, EMBEDDING_SIZE, 1])

conv1, pool1 = cnn(word_list, FILTER_SHAPE1, 'CNN_Layer1')
```

The function `cnn` and the other parameters are as defined

```
MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH = 100
N_FILTERS = 10
FILTER_SHAPE1 = [20, 20]
POOLING_WINDOW = 4
POOLING_STRIDE = 2
MAX_LABEL = 15
EMBEDDING_SIZE = 20

def cnn(x, filter_shape, name):
    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
            x,
            filters=N_FILTERS,
            kernel_size=filter_shape,
            padding='VALID',
            activation=tf.nn.relu)
        pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(
            conv1,
            pool_size=POOLING_WINDOW,
            strides=POOLING_STRIDE,
            padding='SAME')

    return conv1, pool1
```

Comment: Most probably you will get by both errors by simply checking your tensor shapes. Could you verify that they are all correct? And also could you please add the shapes of your input and filters which are causing trouble?

Comment: I'm quite positive it is correct without the embedded layer. not very sure how to properly implement it to be use with CNN